# Tensorflow model error after weight Quantization

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

After quantizing the weights of a model and then saving it for TF Serving, I am able to get the prediction, albeit a  slower than before.

However, after [Quantizing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#optimizing-for-deployment) the weights as well as the model and then saving it for serving and using it I am getting the following error from the client
Running this on V100 in tf-serving docker containers ( tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu) - both client and models

> _Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED   details = "Broadcast between [1,9,4] and
>   [221,1,4] is not supported yet.    [[{{node
>   anchors_3/add_2/eightbit}}]]   [[{{node
>   filtered_detections/map/while/non_max_suppression_47/NonMaxSuppressionV3}}]]"
>     debug_error_string =
>   "{"created":"@1552349235.607723578","description":"Error received from
>   peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"Broadcast
>   between [1,9,4] and [221,1,4] is not supported yet.\n\t [[{{node
>   anchors_3/add_2/eightbit}}]]\n\t [[{{node
>   filtered_detections/map/while/non_max_suppression_47/NonMaxSuppressionV3}}]]","grpc_status":12}"

In TF Serving side, I get the following error

> 2019-03-12 00:07:13.149087: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_add_op.cc:546]
>   ndims=3 2019-03-12 00:07:13.149233: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_add_op.cc:547]
>   bcast.x_reshape()=[1,9,4] 2019-03-12 00:07:13.149309: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_add_op.cc:549]
>   bcast.y_reshape()=[221,1,4] 2019-03-12 00:07:13.149348: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_add_op.cc:551]
>   bcast.x_bcast()=[221,1,1] 2019-03-12 00:07:13.149385: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/quantized_add_op.cc:553]
>   bcast.y_bcast()=[1,9,1]

Model is an image detection model

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input_image'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
        name: input_1_2:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['filtered_detections/map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3:0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 4)
        name: filtered_detections/map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3:0
    outputs['filtered_detections/map/TensorArrayStack_1/TensorArrayGatherV3:0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300)
        name: filtered_detections/map/TensorArrayStack_1/TensorArrayGatherV3:0
    outputs['filtered_detections/map/TensorArrayStack_2/TensorArrayGatherV3:0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 300)
        name: filtered_detections/map/TensorArrayStack_2/TensorArrayGatherV3:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: Can you try performing the inference using "saved_model_cli run" and confirm if you are facing issue with that as well. You can refer this link for more info, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#run_command